# Fade in a movie from white with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an AVI file and I want to create a fade effect, **BUT**  I want the fade-in to begin with white, meaning I want the first frame to be white and the movie should slowly (and continuously) appear from that.

I managed to create a fade-in from black using ffmpeg, by using:

```
ffmpeg -i movie -acodec copy -filter:0 fade=in:0:100 output
```

I am using Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: I found a way in window movie maker. in viusal effect "fade in from white". But still I would appriciate a way to do it with ffmpeg.

Comment: Might be possible in conjunction with the `color` video source, but I don't know how to implement that. There's a good chance that you'll get an answer on the [ffmpeg-user mailing list](http://ffmpeg.org/contact.html).

Answer (score 0):

For a fade-in from white, you can use the `color=XY` argument of the `fade` filter:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:0 fade=in:0:15:color=white output.mp4
```

The fade-in begins on the 0th frame in full white and ends on the 15th frame with transparency (ie. the input source video is fully visible).

Docs for the filter and ffmpeg in general: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#fade

For a fade-out at the end of the video, you'd use

```
-filter:0 fade=out:4465:15:color=white
```

where 4465 is the length of the video in frames.